# Laravel 5.6 dynamic pages from a database best practice

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using/learning Laravel 5.6 and wondered if this is the best approach in trying to accomplish dynamic pages from a database.

The approach I have taken works but I feel it could be improved especially with having to retrieve the pages for the navigation bar with every request.

I have a route in web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@show');
```

I then have my page controller with index and show functions.

```
 public function index()
{
    $pages = Page::all();
    $posts = Post::latest('created_at')->paginate(2);
    return view('index', compact('posts','pages'));
}

public function show($uri)
{
    $pages = Page::all();
    $page = Page::where('uri', $uri)->first();
    return view('templates.page', compact('page','pages'));
}
```

Now in my header.blade.php I display the list of pages like this:

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
     <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/{{ $page->uri }}">{{ $page->title }}</a>
     </li>
@endforeach
```

Now my problem is with all the other controllers I have to get the page's information from the database everytime which seems inefficient.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can share your pages data with every view automatically by [adding `View::share('key', 'value');`in the boot method of a service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). Alternatively you can create a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers).

Answer (score 0):

one layout blade.
yield title by

```
<title>@yield('page-title')</title>
```

then on view,

//process title using php from DB

then display using

```
@section('page-title')
{{$page_title}}
@endsection
```